# Equation solving; three expressions as squares

Tags: number-theory

If positive integer $x,y$ satisfy,
$$2x^2+x=3y^2+y$$ then $x-y,2(x+y)+1,3(x+y)+1$ are perfect squares.

I somehow managed to prove $x-y$ is a perfect square but couldn't prove the others.

Comment: LaTex formatting is quite easy to learn. Just click on the edit button of other people's similar questions and notice, by trial-and-error, which Latex symbols do what. (But don't press save.)

Answer (score 2):

$2x^2+x=3y^2+y\Longrightarrow (x-y)(3x+3y+1)=x^2$. Now observe if a prime $p$ divides both the factors, $x-y$ and $3x+3y+1$ on the LHS, then $p^2$ divides $x^2$ and so $p$ divides $x$. 
Now, $p$ divides $x$ and $p$ divides $x-y$ implies $p$ divides $y$. But this is a contradiction as $p$ divides $3x+3y+1$. So we can conclude that the two factors on LHS are co prime. Now if two co prime numbers multiply to yield a perfect square, then each of them should be perfect squares.
Now observe again that the given equation is equivalent to $(x-y)(2x+2y+1)=y^2$. A similar reasoning follows.

Comment: It would be better to use a new variable at the end of the first equation, as the square is not $x^2$

Answer (score 1):

It became interesting for the General case. When the difference is a square?

Given:

$$ax^2+x=by^2+y\tag1$$

If you use the solutions of the Pell equation

$$p^2-abs^2=\pm1$$

Then solutions to $(1)$ are

$$x=\pm(p+bs)s$$

$$y=\pm(p+as)s$$

$p,s$ - can be of any sign. So the difference will be equal to

$$x-y=\pm(b-a)s^2$$

Comment: Hence, $$\begin{aligned}
ax^2+x &= by^2+y\\
x-y &= (b-a)s^2\\
a(x+y)+1 &= (p+as)^2\\
b(x+y)+1 &= (p+bs)^2\\
\end{aligned}$$ where the OP had $a,b = 2,3$.